# Is it possible to get the keycode not tha Native keycode in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to get the keycode(String) not the Native keycode in GWT keyUP event handler I tried but I only can get the native keycode which returns the ASCII of the key.  Is it possible to get the string of the keycode?

I recognize that GWT does not use some java JREs they only use the JREs they found it useful:(...really disappointed.  I have to write a donkey work code in order to get functions that do the same work as the lost JREs from GWT and here is my code to solve that issue...which i feel of shame to write such code but GWT made me have no other choice if any one can help please!

```
if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==13)
            {
                code="Enter";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==65)
            {
                code="A";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==66)
            {
                code="B";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==67)
            {
                code="C";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==68)
            {
                code="D";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==69)
            {
                code="E";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==70)
            {
                code="F";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==71)
            {
                code="G";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==72)
            {
                code="H";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==73)
            {
                code="I";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==74)
            {
                code="J";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==75)
            {
                code="K";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==76)
            {
                code="L";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==77)
            {
                code="M";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==78)
            {
                code="N";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==79)
            {
                code="O";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==80)
            {
                code="P";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==81)
            {
                code="Q";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==82)
            {
                code="R";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==83)
            {
                code="S";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==84)
            {
                code="T";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==85)
            {
                code="U";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==86)
            {
                code="V";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==87)
            {
                code="W";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==88)
            {
                code="X";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==89)
            {
                code="Y";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==90)
            {
                code="Z";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==48)
            {
                code="0";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==49)
            {
                code="1";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==50)
            {
                code="2";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==51)
            {
                code="3";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==52)
            {
                code="4";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==53)
            {
                code="5";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==54)
            {
                code="6";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==55)
            {
                code="7";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==56)
            {
                code="8";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==57)
            {
                code="9";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==96)
            {
                code="Numpad 0";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==97)
            {
                code="Numpad_1";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==98)
            {
                code="Numpad_2";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==99)
            {
                code="Numpad_3";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==100)
            {
                code="Numpad_4";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==101)
            {
                code="Numpad_5";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==102)
            {
                code="Numpad_6";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==103)
            {
                code="Numpad_7";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==104)
            {
                code="Numpad_8";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==105)
            {
                code="Numpad_9";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==106)
            {
                code="Multiply";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==107)
            {
                code="Add";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==109)
            {
                code="Subtract";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==110)
            {
                code="Decimal";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==111)
            {
                code="Divide";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==8)
            {
                code="BackSpace";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==9)
            {
                code="Tab";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==16)
            {
                code="Shift";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==17)
            {
                code="Control";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==20)
            {
                code="Caps_Lock";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==27)
            {
                code="ESC";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==32)
            {
                code="Space";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==33)
            {
                code="Page_Up";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==34)
            {
                code="Page_Down";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==35)
            {
                code="End";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==36)
            {
                code="Home";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==37)
            {
                code="Left_Arrow";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==38)
            {
                code="Up_Arrow";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==39)
            {
                code="Right_Arrow";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==40)
            {
                code="Down_Arrow";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==45)
            {
                code="Insert";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==46)
            {
                code="Delete";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==144)
            {
                code="Num_Lock";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==145)
            {
                code="ScrLk";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==186)
            {
                code=";";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==187)
            {
                code="=";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==189)
            {
                code="-";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==191)
            {
                code="/";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==192)
            {
                code="`";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==219)
            {
                code="[";
            }

            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==221)
            {
                code="]";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==222)
            {
                code="'";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==188)
            {
                code=",";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==190)
            {
                code=".";
            }
            if((int)event.getNativeKeyCode()==191)
            {
                code="/";
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [Keycodes](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyCodes.java?r=4790) class. It provides constants you can use instead.

Example:

```
switch (event.getNativeKeyCode()) {
    case KeyCodes.ENTER: break;
    case KeyCodes.KEY_P: break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But unfortunately Keycodes doesn't provide all the buttons only about 15 or 20 buttons i need to get the key Text for all buttons in keyboard even the Numpad....but what disappoint me that GWT doesn't contain the JRE for awt.event :(:( any suggestions????

Comment: You can only use a very small subset of the JRE, as the Java code gets compiled to Javascript.

Comment: for the letters, you can use: 'A' or 'a' for instance

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly ure what you mean but it might be simply that your using the wrong key event. If i recall on some browsers keydown or is it keypress  deliver different things , one gives codes the other chars.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, keydown/keyup events are for "keys" while keypress is for "printable chars". If you want "chars", then use a KeyPressHandler instead. Firefox will fire too many events (i.e. even for non-printable chars) but you can easily tell, as the charCode will then be 0.

Is there any reason you really want to do that in keyup?

Comment: Really even in the keypress event i only get some printable chars of the key codes not all, in fact i'm not sure that they retrieve the Strings of the keycode....for example when I press the Key Enter i got a string s which contain a string enter??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see/read the code snippet. First, I'd use a `switch...case` (or maybe even an array –because arrays are sparse in JS– or a `Map`) instead of a river of `if...else if`, then you'll notice that most keycodes map to the ASCII code of the key they represent (keycode 65 == "A" whose code point is... 65!)